# Dockerfile "rm -Rf" fail

Tags: docker

I have a very simple dockerfile, with "rm -Rf" to remove installation files after installation, but I got some error like:

```
Step 4/4 : RUN rm -Rf /INSTALLATION
 ---> Running in 19fe828f3c9d
rm: cannot remove '/INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common': Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove '/INSTALLATION/Subsystems/EMS': Directory not empty
```

I run all with root user.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM centos
COPY INSTALLATION/ /INSTALLATION/ 
RUN  rm -Rf /INSTALLATION
```

My OS is centos7, and host OS is RHLE 7.

Docker info

```
[root@snap460c03 1]# docker info
Containers: 53
 Running: 27
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 26
Images: 19
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
Operating System: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.1 (Maipo)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 24
Total Memory: 94.41 GiB
Name: snap460c03
ID: T3ST:6DXJ:SDST:3W3J:Z4NB:UXF7:HGSZ:A3WH:ELHX:GVZW:APTD:7ZEK
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Http Proxy: http://16.85.88.10:8080/
No Proxy: docker-registry
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 docker-registry:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I also tried new a container and try it manually, but the result is error too:

```
[root@devvm13 1]# docker run -it e20c9c5ffa8a /bin/bash

[root@f3efa193700d /]# rm -Rf /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common/*

[root@f3efa193700d /]# rm -Rf /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common 

rm: cannot remove '/INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common': Directory not empty
```

You can see the second rm is fail, I tried rmdir, the resule is error too.

While I ls the directory, it show:

```
ls /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common
ls: cannot access /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common/eium-license.config: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common/install_jdk.sh: No such file or directory
eium-license.config  install_jdk.sh
```

You can it said no such file but follow with files.

Comment: Did you check which files are left over in these directories?

Comment: What does `rm -R` do as opposed to `rm -r` ?

Comment: @Thilo `-r, -R, --recursive` are synonyms, they all do the same.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, after spending few hours found this issue :- 
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/27358

So Long story short, here is how I fixed it.

When you do a docker info, in your output you have `Storage Driver: overlay`, I had the same, what I did was changing overlay to devicemapper. Follow the instructions showed here - https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/#configure-docker-with-the-devicemapper-storage-driver

You will have to stop and start the docker service also.

**Note :** 
Once you change you will loose all your past images, means you will not see any images/containers when you type `docker images` or `docker ps`. They will be there in fileSystem they will take disk space. So you will have to manually delete that directory, so it will be under `/var/lib/docker/overlay`.

Answer (score 3):

This is your issue:

```
Supports d_type: false
```

You are probably facing this:
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31283

You will need to reformat the xfs file system like:

```
mkfs -t xfs -n ftype=1 -f /path/to/device
```

(we needed the force option somehow).

More info:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/overlayfs-driver/

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/7.2_Release_Notes/technology-preview-file_systems.html

Answer (score 0):

wow,you solve my problem.

```
Removing intermediate container 7563494fcca4
 ---> c277a4f8cb76
Step 3/5 : RUN rm -rf /var/jenkins_home
 ---> Running in 09b23bc50939
rm: cannot remove '/var/jenkins_home': Permission denied
The command '/bin/sh -c rm -rf /var/jenkins_home' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

then

```
Step 3/5 : RUN rm -rf /var/jenkins_home/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fda46f6a9d2e
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is a know issue with docker.

You can try the following as a workaround :

```
RUN  rm -Rf /INSTALLATION/*
```

Comment: I even tried to operate it manually, the result is error too:[root@devvm13 1]# docker run -it e20c9c5ffa8a /bin/bash
[root@f3efa193700d /]# rm -Rf /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common/*
[root@f3efa193700d /]# rm -Rf /INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common  
rm: cannot remove '/INSTALLATION/Subsystems/Common': Directory not empty

Comment: If the /INSTALLATION has chid folder, the result is error too.

Comment: Can you `cd` into the installation directory and check the permissions for the directory using `namei -l .` .If you do not have write permission for that directory , try removing it using `sudo`.

Comment: I am using root for all operations already, looks not like a permission issue.